# Type mismatch in onCreateLoader using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cursorloader

I'm porting an Android app from java to Kotlin. I have a cursor loader to populate a RecyclerView, Everything is fine in Java, but when I try "translate" the code from java to Kotlin I got the message from android studio that you can see in the image below.

My code in java is:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args){
    return new CursorLoader(getContext(), Contrato.URI_CONTENIDO_BASE, null,null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data){

    adaptador.swapCursor(data);

    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(adaptador.getItemCount() -1);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){

}
```

And the code in Kotlin is:

```
override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
    return CursorLoader(context,MMDContract.columnas.CONTENT_BASE_URI, null, null, null, null)
}

override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>?, data: Cursor?) {
  adapter.swapCursor(data)
}

override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>?) {
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

}
```

[image: onCreateLoader in Kotlin]

I haven´t finded official documentation in Kotlin, only in Java. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders

Any idea of how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
return CursorLoader(context,
  MMDContract.columnas.CONTENT_BASE_URI, null, null, null, null)
```

into

```
return CursorLoader(context,
  MMDContract.columnas.CONTENT_BASE_URI, null, null, null, null) as Loader<Cursor>
```

should resolve this.

This error looks like a IDE bug. If you can always see the same error message you may report it on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/.